# How to improve a merge sort algorithm with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, mergesort

I'm trying to improve my code execution time with OpenMP. I'm doing a research on parallelism and testing different ways of implement it.

I tried dividing my array in 4 and I want to run my code in 4 cores (each part in one core) and then merging everything.

So, I slice it and run 4 mergeSorts using: `#pragma omp single nowait`, but I think I'm not doing it on the right way, because it is using about 1,5 Core only. What can I need to change to make what I need? (Sorry I'm new on OpenMP, I'm a computer science student and I'm doing this as class research).

Also, I have a slowdown because I need to do extra merges because it is split in four parts (my execution time is about twice slower then the simple parallel way.

Here is my full code (other improvement tips are welcome):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include "omp.h"
using namespace std;

int n = 60000000;
int * Vet = new int [60000000];
double startTime, stopTime;

void generate_list(int * x, int n) {
   int i,j,t;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     x[i] = i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     j = rand() % n;
     t = x[i];
     x[i] = x[j];
     x[j] = t;
   }
}

void merge(int aux[], int left, int middle, int right){
    int * temp = new int [middle-left+1];
    int * temp2 = new int[right-middle];
    for(int i=0; i<(middle-left+1); i++){
        temp[i]=aux[left+i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<(right-middle); i++){
        temp2[i]=aux[middle+1+i];
    }
    int i=0, j=0, k=left;
    while(i<(middle-left+1) && j<(right-middle))
    {
        if(temp[i]<temp2[j]){
            aux[k++]=temp[i++];
        }
        else{
            aux[k++]=temp2[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<(middle-left+1)){
        aux[k++]=temp[i++];
    }
    while(j<(right-middle)){
        aux[k++]=temp2[j++];
    }
}

void mergeSortSerial(int aux[], int left, int right){
    if (left < right){
        int middle = (left + right)/2;
        mergeSortSerial(aux,left,middle); //call 1
        mergeSortSerial(aux,middle+1,right); //call 2
        merge(aux,left,middle,right);
    }
}

void mergeSort (int aux[], int left, int right){
    if (left < right){
        if ((right-left) > 1000){
            int middle = (left + right)/2;
           #pragma omp task firstprivate (aux, left, middle)
                mergeSort(aux,left,middle); //call 1
            #pragma omp task firstprivate (aux, middle, right)
                mergeSort(aux,middle+1,right); //call 2
            #pragma omp taskwait
            merge(aux,left,middle,right);
        } else{mergeSortSerial(aux, left, right);}
    }
}

void print(int aux[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<aux[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}



int main(){
    generate_list(Vet, n);
    omp_set_nested(1);
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    //startTime = clock();
    int middle = n/2;
    int middleLeft = (n) / 4;
    int middleRight = 3 * (n) / 4;
       #pragma omp parallel
   {
      #pragma omp single nowait
        mergeSort(Vet, 0, middleLeft);
      #pragma omp single nowait
        mergeSort(Vet, middleLeft+1, middle);
      #pragma omp single nowait
        mergeSort(Vet, middle+1, middleRight);
      #pragma omp single nowait
        mergeSort(Vet, middleRight+1, n);
    }
        merge(Vet, 0, middleLeft, middle);
        merge(Vet, middle+1, middleRight, n);
        merge(Vet, 0, n/2, n);



    //stopTime = clock();
    cout<<is_sorted(Vet,Vet+n)<<endl;
    //print(Vet, n);
    //printf("\nSorted in (aprox.): %f seconds \n\n", (double)(stopTime-startTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: "because it is using about 1,5 Core only." what does that mean? how can it use half a core?

Comment: It's using 100% of a CPU and about 40-50% of other.

Comment: and your question is how to make it utilize 100% of both?

Comment: I want to split it in 4 CPU's, don't need to use 100% of all, here's my result of ```perf stat```:
https://pastebin.com/X4DxCcM4

Comment: maybe I'm a little lost on multithreading concepts, but I'm still learning it

Comment: Did you test if the output of your sort is correct? For the part of usage of the CPUs, one possible problem could be the placement of threads. You can control this through  the OMP_PROC_BIND env variable, set it to "spread" for example. It is quite bizarre  the usage of single this way. Read about OpenMP tasks and try to implement it using task-based programming (internally for most of the OpenMP implementations express everything as tasks). Be careful also on all the variable that are used in the parallel region. U should precise how are they used (shared, private, firstprivate etc).

Comment: It is not an answer but just a pointers on what you should take into account.    p.s. the line where you calculate middleRight could be interpreted differently. protect the division with parenthesis. GOOD LUCK

Comment: @coyotemk, yes, I used ```std::is_sorted()``` to check and it's sorted. I will search about what you adviced me. Thank you

Comment: Also, I know i'm doing it the wrong way, I'm trying to discover the right way to split the array iterations on the CPU's (I splited it in 4, 1 for each CPU).